# dúvidas com o try catch

Tags: java, try-catch

Estou com uma dúvida aqui com o uso de try-catch numa atividade

O professor pediu que fizéssemos uma calculadora com o uso de try-catch caso o usuário **digita-se 0 (zero)**. Já vi alguns exemplos e possuo até um esqueleto aqui baseado em alguns códigos que ele passou em aula. Dá uma forcinha ai galera <3

```
public class TestaCalculadora {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double p1=0, p2=0;
        char op=' ';
        boolean continua=true, continua2=true;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            do {
                try {   
                    System.out.print("Número: ");
                    p1 = sc.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Operador: ");
                    op = sc.next().charAt(0);
                    continua=false;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Insira apenas números.");
                    sc.nextLine(); 
                }
            } while(continua);
            do {
                try {   
                    do {
                        System.out.print("Número: ");
                        p2 = sc.nextDouble();
                        switch (op) {
                        case '+':
                            p1=Calculadora.somar(p1, p2);              
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            p1=Calculadora.subtrair(p1, p2);           
                            break;
                        case '*':
                            p1=Calculadora.multiplicar(p1, p2);        
                            break;
                        case '/':
                            p1=Calculadora.dividir(p1, p2);            
                            break;

                       }
                    System.out.print("Qual o operador ?:  ");
                    op = sc.next().charAt(0);
                } while(op!='=');
                System.out.printf("Resultado = %.2f  ",p1); 
                continua2=false;
                    }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.err.println("Apenas números.");
                    sc.nextLine();
                }
        } while(continua2);

    }
}
```

no caso, o erro desse é quando se digita algo diferente dos caracteres que não seja operadores

Answer (score -1, accepted):

você pode adicionar ao seu Switch:

Default:
System.err.println("Apenas operadores validos.");
break;